# Bootstrap Vertical Align images

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="container-fluid padding" style="margin-top: 150px; margin-bottom: 75px;">

          <div class="row padding images"><!--Image 1-->
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-8">
              <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO4AV.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 vcenter"><!--Image 2-->
              <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO4AV.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 vcenter"><!--Image 3-->
              <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO4AV.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4"><!--Image 4-->
              <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO4AV.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4"><!--Image 5-->
             <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO4AV.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4"><!--Image 6-->
             <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO4AV.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
</div>
```

So image 1 is taking up 8/12 cols and I want image 2 and 3 to vertical align along the right side of image 1 but what happens is that image 2 is on the right side but image 3 ends up below on a new row with image 4-6 are and pushes image 6 down. So what should I do to be able to make image 3 end up under image 2 along /doing vertical align or something like that along side the right side of image 1?

```css
images{
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .images img{
        background-color: red;
        float: left;
        margin: 15px 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        border: 1px solid gray;
      }
```

Comment: you should try using css Grid, example here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_grid_layout_named

Comment: If it is hardcoded, put  `img` 2 and 3 in the second column. Otherwise, use [`masonary`](https://masonry.desandro.com/) layout.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
 img{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 }

 .paddimages{
  padding: 0;
 }
```

HTML

```
 <div class="container-fluid padding" style="margin-top: 150px; margin-bottom: 75px;">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 paddimages"><!--Image 1-->
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO4AV.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 paddimages"><!--Image 2 and Image 3-->

            <div class="row">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO4AV.jpg" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO4AV.jpg" alt="">
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>  

    <div class="row">   

        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 paddimages"><!--Image 4-->
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO4AV.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 paddimages"><!--Image 5-->
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO4AV.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 paddimages"><!--Image 6-->
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO4AV.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

    </div>

 </div>
```